# Phonegap angularjs $http.post() always returns http code 200

Tags: angularjs, cordova, django-rest-framework

Angularjs v. 1.2.0rc3 with phonegap 3.1 and django-rest-framework

When posting data to my API (login form) I am getting status 200 in angularjs no matter if I authenticate with proper credentials etc. Even though I simply return HTTP_400 in the API view as in the example below, angularjs thinks this is a HTTP_200 status code. 
I am sure the backend API returns HTTP_400 which works fine when using local http server. 
I can also confirm this by debugging the api view.

Here's the example code.
Django Rest Framework code:

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and my angularjs controller:

```
$scope.login = function () {
    $http.post(API_URL, $scope.loginUser).then(
        function(response) {
            console.log('STATUS : ' + response.status);
            console.log('request OK');
        },
        function() {
            console.log('request is NOT OK');
        )};
```

As far as I know phonegap uses a local file:// protocol so there should be no CORS
related problem ?

When the same on chrome browser, I get **Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**.  Adding --disable-web-security flag to chrome startup script eliminates this problem but it does not solve the "always 200 status code" for phonegap.

Testing on android 2.3 & phonegap 3.1 & angularjs 1.2.0rc3

Comment: Seems like this is an angularjs problem: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4436

Comment: I am having the same issue using angular 1.2.0rc3 and phonegap 3.1. Even though the server returns status code 401 in my interceptor it still shows up as status 200. Same issue persists in 1.2 stable also.

Comment: By the way I did not have this problem with angular 1.2.0rc2, so could you please try that and report back.

Comment: Too bad [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4514) patch which potentially fixes the issue wasn't merged before stable release.

Comment: same issue for me. It doesnt capture 401, 404 status codes of error callback, but it works on webserver serving files to browser

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed fixed in AngularJS 1.2.3

See the line here: 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.3/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L122

Comment: Consider an Up-Vote for sharing the actual line of code :D

Comment: Confirmed. Upgraded from 1.2.1 to 1.2.3 and the problems was indeed resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Latest(version 1.2.9) AngularJS version, Its resolved now.